# light won't pass through the windows

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, light, transparency

[image]So I am still very new to Blender, having only been working with it for about a week, but I am at the point where I am trying to get lighting set up for a Minecraft animation that I'm making for my channel but I can't get light to show up indoors. I can see through the windows but light won't pass through the windows nor will any lamps work that are placed inside. Can someone help me figure out how to fix this?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: I am using Blender Render

Comment: you may have to upload the .blend to PasteAll.org and paste the link here.  Then again, maybe someone will recognize the problem without seeing the setup. :)

Comment: That website won't let me upload my file @MarcClintDion

Comment: too big?  You can always make a duplicate of the file and delete most of the models and textures.  Only a small portion should be needed to diagnose the issue.

Comment: I tried t osolve this with a mix-material, using a RGB Mix node for the alpha values, depending on the texture of the glass.
But the shadow under the object stays filled, it seems to be non dependent on the mix materials alpha value. I'd like to know how to do this too, any ideas, someone?

Comment: If you are going to upload your .blend file the site standard is to use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and edit the resulting link into your original question.

Answer (score 3):

The calculation of transparent shadows is a little bit slow, so the casting of transparent shadows (behind your glass) is deactivated in the default settings. To get the shadows or better the light you have to activate **Receive Transparent** in the Shadow-Settings in the material tab for each Material, wich receive light through an object.

[image]< activate **Receive Transparent**

see [Shadows](http://blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/materials/properties/shadows.html#shadow-receiving-object-material) in the Blender Manual